# Matplotlib x-axis default labels won't go away

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I'm working on a dataset and I'm having some weird results. I've created a grid and I'm trying to have the x-axis labels only show up for the bottom graphs and show years. However, the default a-xis label is staying on in the background. I've tried many different things, but no luck. What gives?

Code:

```py
fig, ((ax1, ax2, ax3), 
      (ax4, ax5, ax6), 
      (ax7, ax8, ax9), 
      (ax10, ax11, ax12), 
      (ax13, ax14, ax15), 
      (ax16, ax17, ax18)) = plt.subplots(6, 3, figsize=(30, 60),
                                          sharex=True, sharey=True)
```

And...

[image]

Result:

Red lines point to the little buggers...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're creating two sets of axes, once in the `plt.subplots()` call, and then again with your subsequent `fig.add_subplot()` calls.

You can modify your first call to just create the figure by doing the following:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (30, 60))
```

...and then impose the axis-sharing on the calls that add the subplots:

```
for sp in range(0, 16, 3):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(6, 3, sp, sharex = True, sharey = True)
```

Alternatively, if you want to create all of the subplots first and then access them in your for loop:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(6, 3, figsize = (30, 60), sharex = True, sharey = True) 
for sp in range(0, 16, 3):
    ax = axes[sp]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks Ken. I tried to give an upvote but it won't let me since I'm a newb. Cheers and stay safe!

Comment: @KennethWaynescott You’re welcome. If you can, please accept the answer!